# Comparing the values of two text-fields using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

**Consider the following HTML tables:**

```
<table id="myTable1">
    <tr><td><input type="text" id="quantity1" name="quantity1" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text" id="quantity2" name="quantity2" /></td></tr>
</table>

<table id="myTable2">
    <tr><td>
        <input type="text" id="total_quantity" name="total_quantity" />
        <input type="text" id="total_quantity_max" name="total_quantity_max" />
    </td></tr>
</table>
```

- **total_quantity_max** contains a constant integer value, whereas
- **total_quantity** will hold the **SUM** value based on the values of the **quantity** fields
- value of **total_quantity** is updated everytime keyup is triggered on the **quantity** fields

What I'm trying to do is to alert the user the instant that the value in **total_quantity** becomes greater than the value in **total_quantity_max.**

At first I thought this could be achieved with something like:

```
$('#myTable1 input[id^=quantity]').live('keyup',function() {
    var n = $("#myTable2 #total_quantity").val();
    var m = $("#myTable2 #total_quantity_max").val();

    if(n > m) {
        alert("Alert!");
    }
});
```

However I'm encountering problems using the above code such as; the alert gets triggered even though the value in **total_quantity** clear is not **> total_quantity_max**.

Comment: You're comparing strings, not actual numbers..

Comment: what are the actual values you get for n and m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the comparison is done with string and not number. Try to use `parseFloat`.

```
$('#myTable1 input[id^=quantity]').live('keyup',function() {
    var n = $("#myTable2 #total_quantity").val();
    var m = $("#myTable2 #total_quantity_max").val();

    if(parseFloat(n) > parseFloat(m)) {
        alert("Alert!");
    }
});
```

Comment: Ah Strings. I always assumed those are automatically read as integers. Thanks the code's working now!

Answer (score 2):

Use `parseInt` - `val` will return a string and strings have different comparison rules from integers.

```
if(parseInt(n, 10) > parseInt(m, 10)) {
    alert("Alert!");
}
```

Comment: Always use `parseInt(n,10)`. If n were `09` and m were `04`, your if statement would fail.

Comment: Nah, he should use TryParse, if his string contains anything else than a number it would fail anyway

Comment: @Rob You mean [this C# function?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx)